# python scrapin .aspx from cbi

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm beginner in python and I am trying to scrapping a link from central bank of Iran.
i tried this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r_obj = requests.Session()

url = "https://www.cbi.ir/PolicyRates/policyrates_fa.aspx"

fr_soup = r_obj.get(url)
print(fr_soup)


soup = BeautifulSoup(fr_soup.content , "lxml")
print(soup)

l = soup.find_all("input",type="hidden")
print(l)

data = {
l[0]['name']:l[0]['value'],
l[1]['name']:l[1]['value'],
'btnAccept':'Yes, I accept'}

r_obj.post(url,verify=False,data=data)

url_needed = "https://www.cbi.ir/PolicyRates/policyrates_fa.aspx"

final = r_obj.get(url_needed)
```

but I got this:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 19>()
     15 l = soup.find_all("input",type="hidden")
     16 print(l)
     18 data = {
---> 19 l[0]['name']:l[0]['value'],
     20 l[1]['name']:l[1]['value'],
     21 'btnAccept':'Yes, I accept'}
     23 r_obj.post(url,verify=False,data=data)
     25 url_needed = "https://www.cbi.ir/PolicyRates/policyrates_fa.aspx"

IndexError: list index out of range
```

and i don't know about **value**!

i want to get this table and then use pandas.
Thanks,

Comment: If you only try and print out `soup`, do you see that element there?

Comment: No, I can't find it. i want to work with the table in the link. but i can't get the data.

Comment: That page's content is being generated by javascript (not even pulled from an API, but generated off an unknown encoding object present in one of the script tags). The easiest way would probably be using selenium to scrape it. Are you open to a solution based off Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that page is generated by a js script, here is a solution based off selenium/chromedriver. You will probably need to install selenium, download chromedriver executable, and set everything up depending on your machine/OS. There are many easy to follow tutorials on the net, and also, the Selenium documentation can be found here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

The following code will get all three tables from that page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import pandas as pd


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.cbi.ir/PolicyRates/policyrates_fa.aspx'

browser.get(url) 

for x in range(3):
    select_element = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='ctl00_ucBody_ucContent_ctl00_ddlYear']"))))

    select_element.select_by_index(x)
    t.sleep(5)
    table_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ctl00_ucBody_ucContent_ctl00_divRates']/table")))
    df = pd.read_html(table_element.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
    print(f'TABLE {x}')
    print(df)
```

This will return:

```
TABLE 0
تاریخ   نرخ بازار بین‌بانکی(%)  حداقل نرخ توافق بازخرید(%)  نرخ اعتبارگیری قاعده​‌مند(%)    نرخ سپرده‌گذاری قاعده‌​مند(%)
0   ۱۴۰۱/۰۵/۱۳  20.64   20  22  14
1   ۱۴۰۱/۰۵/۱۲  20.64   20  22  14
2   ۱۴۰۱/۰۵/۰۶  21.13   21.5    22  14
3   ۱۴۰۱/۰۴/۳۰  21.31   21.21   22  14
4   ۱۴۰۱/۰۴/۲۳  21.14   20.91   22  14
5   ۱۴۰۱/۰۴/۱۶  20.95   20.3    22  14
6   ۱۴۰۱/۰۴/۰۹  20.85   19.8    22  14
7   ۱۴۰۱/۰۴/۰۲  20.82   19.5    22  14
8   ۱۴۰۱/۰۳/۲۶  20.68   19.3    22  14
9   ۱۴۰۱/۰۳/۱۹  20.57   19.2    22  14
10  ۱۴۰۱/۰۳/۱۲  20.55   19.1    22  14
11  ۱۴۰۱/۰۳/۰۵  20.59   19.01   22  14
12  ۱۴۰۱/۰۲/۲۹  20.57   19  22  14
13  ۱۴۰۱/۰۲/۲۲  20.45   19  22  14
14  ۱۴۰۱/۰۲/۱۵  20.44   19  22  14
15  ۱۴۰۱/۰۲/۰۸  20.40   19  22  14
16  ۱۴۰۱/۰۲/۰۱  20.36   19  22  14
17  ۱۴۰۱/۰۱/۲۵  20.29   19  22  14
18  ۱۴۰۱/۰۱/۱۸  20.30   19  22  14
19  ۱۴۰۱/۰۱/۱۱  20.36   -   22  14
TABLE 1
تاریخ   نرخ بازار بین‌بانکی(%)  حداقل نرخ توافق بازخرید(%)  نرخ اعتبارگیری قاعده​‌مند(%)    نرخ سپرده‌گذاری قاعده‌​مند(%)
0   ۱۴۰۰/۱۲/۲۶  20.28   19  22  14
1   ۱۴۰۰/۱۲/۱۹  20.25   19  22  14
2   ۱۴۰۰/۱۲/۱۲  20.30   19  22  14
3   ۱۴۰۰/۱۲/۰۵  20.33   19  22  14
4   ۱۴۰۰/۱۱/۲۸  20.26   19  22  14
5   ۱۴۰۰/۱۱/۲۱  20.31   19  22  14
6   ۱۴۰۰/۱۱/۱۴  20.39   19.2    22  14
7   ۱۴۰۰/۱۱/۰۷  20.45   19.2    22  14
8   ۱۴۰۰/۱۰/۳۰  20.48   19.3    22  14
9   ۱۴۰۰/۱۰/۲۳  20.50   19.3    22  14
10  ۱۴۰۰/۱۰/۱۶  20.85   19.3    22  14
11  ۱۴۰۰/۱۰/۰۹  21.11   20.15   22  14
12  ۱۴۰۰/۱۰/۰۲  21.08   20.15   22  14
13  ۱۴۰۰/۰۹/۲۵  21.04   20.15   22  14
14  ۱۴۰۰/۰۹/۱۸  21.05   20.15   22  14
[...]
```